# Php, Join two arrays using keys from first and and values from second

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays, one is generated from POST method, and the other one is from database.

```
Post

Array
(
    [browser] => Array
        (
            [0] => Firefox
            [1] => Chrome
        )

    [firstname] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
        )

    [lastname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Doe
        )
)

Database

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Browser Name
            [name] => browser
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => First Name
            [name] => firstname

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Last Name
            [name] => lastname

        )

)
```

I would like to be able to join both using keys from POST array and name value from Database array.

The result should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Browser Name
            [name] => browser
            [posted] => Array (
                  [0] => Firefox
                  [1] => Chrome
            )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => First Name
            [name] => firstname
            [posted] => John

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Last Name
            [name] => lastname
            [posted] => Doe

        )

)
```

It's important to keep the same order from Post array.

Comment: Post your current code, the one to grab datas from database and from the post, then to merge boths.

Comment: @zeflex I don't have the code, that's reason I'm asking for help.

Comment: stackoverflow is an helping community. You have to post something as code, in order to start somewhere before some people can help you.

Comment: I tried using $result = array_merge_recursive($_POST, $data); but that only gets me half way

Comment: You are trying to merge an array and an object. It cannot work. You have to convert the object to an array first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$postArray = array(
    'browser' => array('Firefox', 'Chrome'),
    'firstname' => array('John'),
    'lastname' => array('Doe')
);

$arrayObj1 = new StdClass();
$arrayObj1->title = 'Browser Name';
$arrayObj1->name = 'browser';

$arrayObj2 = new StdClass();
$arrayObj2->title = 'First Name';
$arrayObj2->name = 'firstname';

$arrayObj3 = new StdClass();
$arrayObj3->title = 'Last Name';
$arrayObj3->name = 'lastname';

$dbArray = array($arrayObj1, $arrayObj2);

$finalArray = array();
foreach ($dbArray AS $key => $dbObject) {
    $finalArray[$key] = new StdClass();
    $finalArray[$key]->title = $dbObject->title;
    $finalArray[$key]->name = $dbObject->name;
    if (count($postArray[$dbObject->name]) > 1) {
        $finalArray[$key]->posted = $postArray[$dbObject->name];
    } else {
        $finalArray[$key]->posted = $postArray[$dbObject->name][0];
    }
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```

Tested there: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7bf0fa0fbdb086ae0cc8bb21a78261ca8c05c08e